# Relationship between convexity and a perfect complements type utility function

Tags: microeconomics, preferences, perfect-complements

Consider someone who consume two goods and hates them both. 
Given the utility function:
U(x,y)= -max{x,y}
1.What would be the shape of the indifference curve?
2.Why are these preferences **weakly** convex?
3.What does the negative sign imply mathematically?
4.Will it become an min{x,y} function?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly giving you the answers, I'm going to give you a series of hints to help you figure out the answers on your own.

> 1.What would be the shape of the indifference curve?

Consider three different consumption bundles: $(3,10)$, $(10,10)$, and $(10,3)$. Verify that these three bundles yield the same utility to the consumer. In other words, they should lie on the same indifference curve. Then draw a curve through the three points. Verify that all points described by $(x,10)$ and $(10,y)$ for $x,y\le10$ should also be on this indifference curve.

> 2.Why are these preferences weakly convex?

First remind yourself what *weak convexity* means. Then compare the utilities that the individual gets from the following pairs of bundles:

- $A_1=(10,10)$ and $A_2=\alpha(10,3)+(1-\alpha)(3,10)$ for $\alpha\in(0,1)$
- $B_1=(10,10)$ and $B_2=\alpha(10,3)+(1-\alpha)(10,10)$ for $\alpha\in(0,1)$

> 3.What does the negative sign imply mathematically?

You said that the consumer *hates* both goods. Compare the utilities from the bundles $(10,10)$ and $(5,5)$ and see which is higher (and thus more preferred).

> 4.Will it become an min{x,y} function?

Try sketch an indifference curve for $u=\min\{x,y\}$ and compare to those in part 1.

Comment: Thanks! It was very confusing for me because both goods are bads. Hence I related them somehow to perfect substitutes, with a positive slope.

Answer (score 2):

$u(x, y) = -\max(x, y) = \min(-x, -y)$ is a concave function. Since it is concave, it is also quasiconcave (or equivalently, it represents weakly convex preferences). Here is the indifference map of $u$ :
[image]

$u$ does not represent the same preference as $v(x, y) =\min(x, y)$. Here is the indifference map of $v$ :
[image]

Comment: @B11b What do you mean by "up to today, I never ask a homework"? You have no questions posted today.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that -max(x,y) would be min (-x,-y) instead of min (x, y). Very confusing. I thought the function would mirror itself, e.g. y=x^2 and y=-x^2 So, just to confirm: the curve does not change at all, given the negative sign? (first graph)

Comment: EDIT: will -min (x,y) become max (-x,-y) then? And its curve won't change?